# Group permissions not working properly

Tags: linux, permissions

I have created a folder `/home/public` to share files amongst all my users in my computer. I also have created a group public.

I've recursively changed the group owner to `public` and changed group permissions to `rwx`but I still can not access files that do not belong to the user.

Any idea as to why?

**EDIT:**

```
gamer@pop-os:~$ id
uid=1002(gamer) gid=1002(gamer) groups=1002(gamer),1003(public)

gamer@pop-os:~$ ls -ld /home/public
drwxrwsr-x 4 root public 4096 Nov 16 11:41 /home/public
```

I can open the file below:

```
gamer@pop-os:/home/public/ASIR/Implantación de sistemas operativos/Unidad 3 - Administración de software base I$ ls -ld Configuraciones\ básicas\ SO.pdf
-rw-rwxr-- 1 john public 775221 Nov  9 13:24 'Configuraciones básicas SO.pdf'
```

I can not open this other file that is in the same folder:

```
gamer@pop-os:/home/public/ASIR/Implantación de sistemas operativos/Unidad 3 - Administración de software base I$ ls -ld ISO\ -\ UD3\ -\ Administración\ de\ software\ base\ I 
-rw-rwxr-- 1 john public 1809748 Nov  3 11:46 'ISO - UD3 - Administración de software base I'
```

EDIT 2:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of the commands `ls -ld /home/public`, `ls -ld /home/public/a_file_you _cannot_access` and `id` executed as the user that has the problem.

Comment: If owner permissions denies the owner access, group permissions will not grant the owner access.

Comment: Please use set the setgid on the folder: `chmod g+s /home/public` to make all new files in that folder have the correct group id.

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when you try to open the file?

Comment: @Kusalananda I get `permission denied`

Comment: How are you trying to open the file ?

Comment: @RedaSalih Just double click from GUI

Comment: Try to open it with vi `'/home/public/ASIR/Implantación\ de\ sistemas\ operativos/Unidad\ 3\ -\ Administracion de software\ base'` and `cat '/home/public/ASIR/Implantación\ de\ sistemas\ operativos/Unidad\ 3\ -\ Administracion de software\ base'`  put the output

Comment: @RedaSalih I've tried both commands and I've just got a bunch of gibberish, but the commands do work, if that's your point.

Comment: I wonder if it has anything to do with the lack of a filename suffix. If it's a PDF file, try giving the file a name that ends with `.pdf`. I don't know what your file manager tries to do when you double-click a file with no filename suffix. It may try to _execute_ it.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you! I didn't realize that the file had no extension! i don't understand why it doesnt.

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using ? i think apparmor or selinux is the issue here.

Comment: Also try to open it directly from FileManager.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have two users test1 (gid=public) tets2(gid=public) :

Make sure to execute the above :

```
# Create public dir & group
mkdir /home/public
groupadd public
# Set the ownership / permissions 
chown root:public /home/public
chmod 770 /home/public
# Create the users
useradd -m -g public test1
useradd -m -g public test2
# Set the password for oth users
echo "test1:test1" | chpasswd
echo "test2:test2" | chpasswd
# TEST
ssh test1@<ip>
    cd /home/public/ : OK
    touch /home/public/test.txt : OK
ssh test2@<ip>
    cd /home/public/ : permission denied
    touch /home/public/test.txt : permission denied
```